# Preserve HTML table location after dynamic update

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-table

When I update an HTML table using `appendChild()`, the entire table is moved to the bottom of the document. How do I preserve the location of the table in the DOM?

My example is also posted on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q43p9hy8/3/).

```html
<!--I want the existing table below to stay fixed in place after new rows are added.-->

<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td> Table Cell 1</td>
    <td> Table Cell 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<!--The following button will add rows, but also move the table. How do I stop the move?-->

<input type="button" value="ADD NEW ROWS." onclick="generate_table()">

<script>
  // This function just creates new rows for the table 
  function generate_table() {
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    var tbl = document.getElementById("table");
    var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      var row = document.createElement("tr");
      for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        var cell = document.createElement("td");
        var cellText = document.createTextNode("cell " + i + ", column " + j);
        cell.appendChild(cellText);
        row.appendChild(cell);
      }
      tblBody.appendChild(row);
    }
    tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
    body.appendChild(tbl);
  }
</script>

<style>
  table,
  th,
  td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the following line, you don't need it.

```
body.appendChild(tbl);
```

The table node is already a part of the Document Object Model, you don't need to add it again. By appending the element to body, you are moving it from the current position to the end of the body node.

As a rule of thumb, you need to use `appendChild`, only if the element was created dynamically using `createElement`.